# get all the child attribute value from the xml

Tags: php, javascript, xslt, xpath

this is my simple xml file:-

```
<child_2 entity_id="2" value="Root" parent_id="1">
    <child_4 entity_id="4" value="Activities" parent_id="2">
        <child_10066 entity_id="10066" value="Physical1" parent_id="4">
            <child_10067 entity_id="10067" value="Cricket" parent_id="10066">
                <child_10068 entity_id="10068" value="One Day" parent_id="10067"/>
            </child_10067>
        </child_10066>
        <child_10069 entity_id="10069" value="Test2" parent_id="4"/>
        <child_10070 entity_id="10070" value="Test3" parent_id="4"/>
        <child_10071 entity_id="10071" value="Test4" parent_id="4"/>
        <child_10072 entity_id="10072" value="Test5" parent_id="4"/>
        <child_5 entity_id="5" value="Physical" parent_id="4"/>
    </child_4>
</child_2>
```

i want to get all the child value of `entity_id 4` 
with comma separate `,` and save as text file
**this is my o/p:-**

10066,10067,10068,10069,10070,10071

**this is my try:-**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:key name="kChild" match="*[@entity_id]" use="../@entity_id"/>

  <xsl:param name="region" select="'4'" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kChild', $region)" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="@entity_id"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

thanks

Comment: You need to show what the actual output should look like for the given XML. Your XML is a strange structure with the elements having their ID concatenated within the tag name, I don't see any benefit to that in this example since you have the ID as an attribute.

Comment: @MrCode i update my question please check

Comment: i am add my xslt file...

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the `@entity_id` attribute value of every element whose `@parent_id` value is "4" (or `$region`)?

Comment: @EeroHelenius yes every value have `parent_id = 4` i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `@entity_id` attribute value of every descendant of an element whose `@entity_id` attribute value is `$region`:

#### Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:param name="region" select="'4'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*[@entity_id = $region]//*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="@entity_id"/>
    <!-- Don't add comma after last number -->
    <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Input

```
<child_2 entity_id="2" value="Root" parent_id="1">
  <child_4 entity_id="4" value="Activities" parent_id="2">
    <child_10066 entity_id="10066" value="Physical1" parent_id="4">
      <child_10067 entity_id="10067" value="Cricket" parent_id="10066">
        <child_10068 entity_id="10068" value="One Day" parent_id="10067"/>
      </child_10067>
    </child_10066>
    <child_10069 entity_id="10069" value="Test2" parent_id="4"/>
    <child_10070 entity_id="10070" value="Test3" parent_id="4"/>
    <child_10071 entity_id="10071" value="Test4" parent_id="4"/>
    <child_10072 entity_id="10072" value="Test5" parent_id="4"/>
    <child_5 entity_id="5" value="Physical" parent_id="4"/>
  </child_4>
</child_2>
```

#### Output

```
10066,10067,10068,10069,10070,10071,10072,5
```

Comment: where is 10067,10068 i want all

Comment: Their `@parent_id` attribute value is not "4".

Comment: ohhh i know but want all child value of child_4

Comment: Okay, edited my answer. Did I understand correctly this time?